# python/numpy - How to use einsum in the following example?

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following:

sum_XY C_x I_xk Cy I_yl P_xy

currently my code looks like this:

```
# initialise dummy values
Nk = Nl = 100
NX = Ny = 10
Ix = np.random.rand(Nx, Nk)
Iy = np.random.rand(Ny, Nl)
C = np.random.rand(Nk)
Pin = np.ones(Nx*Ny)

# point 1
Fx = (Ix * C[np.newaxis, :Nk]).T # <- this part may be unavoidable due to using arbitrary precision for Ix, Iy
Fy = (Iy * C[np.newaxis, :Nl]).T # <- this part may be unavoidable due to using arbitrary precision for Ix, Iy
# point 2
H = Fx[:, np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis] * Fy[np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis, :]
H = H.reshape([Nk*Nl, Nx*Ny])
out = np.dot(H, Pin)
out.shape = [Nk, Nl]
# end
```

I was wondering if I could do the above with `np.einsum` somehow as I've ended up using too much memory whenever I try to create H...

Please let me know know if you need additional information.

**EDIT:**

Due to numerical accuracy it may be the case that einsum can only be used effectively from `point 2` onwards. So the question becomes how can I replace the code with `einsum` from `point 1` until the end and from `point 2` until the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with `point2`, this matches your calculation.

```
H2 = np.einsum('kx,ly->klxy', Fx, Fy)
out2 = np.einsum('klxy,xy->kl', H2, np.ones((Nx,Ny)))
print np.allclose(out, out2)
```

I tried to choose einsum indexes to match your shape parameters.  I tested it with

```
Nk, Nl = 100, 90
Nx, Ny = 10, 9
```

just to make sure I wasn't mixing up dimensions.

And since the 2nd einsum just sums over the last 2 dimensions, this simplifies to

```
out4 = np.einsum('kx,ly->kl', Fx, Fy)
```

Including `point1`

```
Fx = np.einsum('xk,k->kx', Ix, C[:Nk])
Fy = np.einsum('yl,l->ly', Iy, C[:Nl])
out5 = np.einsum('kx,ly->kl', Fx, Fy)
print np.allclose(out, out5)
```

or

```
out6 = np.einsum('xk,k,yl,l->kl', Ix, C[:Nk], Iy, C[:Nl])
print np.allclose(out, out6)
```

or mimicing your initial expression:

```
# sum_XY C_x I_xk C_y I_yl P_xy
out7 = np.einsum('k,xk,l,yl,xy->kl', Cx, Ix, Cy, Iy, Pin)
```

However, rolling the calculation into 1 or 2 `einsums` does not necessarily save you time or memory.  For calculations with 2 terms, `einsum` often does as well as `dot`, and better if it saves transposing etc.  But with 3 or 4 terms, `einsum` slows down and uses more memory, since it has to iterate (a C code level) over a larger space.

Comment: hm... so I've ended up using `np.einsum('kx,ly,xy->kl', Fx, Fy, Pin.reshape([Nx, Ny])` and this saves significant amounts of memory. In terms of speed I'd expect it to be as fast-ish as doing the matrix multiplications or? this way I avoid ever creating H